# github desktop enterprise token authentication problem without OAuth access

Tags: git, github, oauth, single-sign-on, github-desktop

I am trying to use github desktop with my IBM enterprise account but I get all the time the following error:

> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.ibm.com/xxx.git/': Failed to connect to github.ibm.com port 443: Timed out

The problem is that i when i enter the enterprise address server the authentication goes to my browser and it gets validate automatically, so i can't use any token. In the app, I can see my repos but when I can't clone them due to the problem above.

I'm not using a proxy

I tried creating a ssh key and actually it work in git but I get the same problem in desktop.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Usually url has username or organization name between ```https://github.ibm.com/``` & ```xxx.git/```. Is it a typo in question?

Comment: no, i just put it in a shorter version

Comment: I can think of 2 options as of now. (1) Open the enterprise github site and log out. This should invalidate your session. So when browser gets triggered from GitHub desktop, you will see login page. (2) Change your default browser. This is indirect way of achieving similar effect as #(1) above.

Comment: I tried both options but it's still the same. I see my enterprise login page and I login in desktop but i can't clone any repository

Comment: Could be something specific to your enterprise github deployment. If possible, check with tech support. As you can't share the network logs, you can check Network section in "Developer Console" of Github Desktop app for any obvious problems while cloning a repo.